# How does SQL Server 2008 run a select query on a machine which has multiple cores?

Tags: sql-server

I need to access a huge amount of data in a short time, so I came up with a solution. I intend to run the same select query using the between clause by changing its parameters, in a parallel manner on the cores available in the cpu.

For this to work I wanted to know whether SQL Server inherently uses all the cores efficiently for a select statement or it just uses a single core for processing the query. I could not find much help on the internet regarding this.

If I could implement this approach on a quad-core, I would increase my access times 4 times than the normal query and this would be affected with change in number of cores.

Is it possible to run multiple threads of a C# application on multiple cores to get parallel execution?

Comment: 99 times out of 98, a sql query is going to be bound by your IO subsystem and not your CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does take parallel queries into account. It is usually avoided as there is some overhead (and it is seldomly possible to do it better manually). The maximum degree can be configured with [sp_configure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181007%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or in a WORKLOAD GROUP and you can specify the MAXDOP hint in selects to change it up/down-wards.

Typically it depends on the IO throughput (especially if data is distributed over multiple path) as well as computational complexity of queries and calculations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's based on the overall cost of the subtree, as defined in the cost threshold for parallelism setting on the instance.

Comment: Yes what I meant is, it depends on the workload if it is actually faster, sql server does not use that as a criteria. @JNK

Comment: Please suggest where can I get an elaborated explanation over this.